# Wordpress: force not HTML escape in text widget?

Tags: html, wordpress, html-entities

I'm using Wordpress with the [Twitter Pro widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-widget-pro/faq/), and I want to include a link in the title. (Actually an image and a link, but keeping the question simple...)

I'm using the following code in a Wordpress text widget in the sidebar.

```
[twitter-widget username="myname" items="5" hiderss="true" 
title="<a href='#'>My Title</a>" hidereplies="true"][/twitter-widget]
```

It works in my version of Chrome, but Firefox HTML-escapes the title, and I end up with:

```
<a href='#'>My Title</a>
```

visible to the naked eye in my sidebar.

What can I do? Is there a way I can force the browser not to HTML-escape this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your theme(functions.php) or widget has this code inside it:

**add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');**

since you are using shortcodes in widget which are not allowed by default in wordpress.